# How can i evaluate a stream (string)

Tags: c#, string, winforms

First of all, what I do at the moment:

I sniff a asyncron serial bus with 9 bit protocol and send the data to the PC. At the PC side I receive the data as an endless string, that looks like that: .12_80E886.02_80E894.13. The Software of the PC-side is written with winforms with C#. Now I have the problem that I haven´t a clearly start you can see it in the stream example. The reason for that is, that I start the sniff somewhere in the protocol.

What I want to do:

I think I can use `startindex = IndexOf("_")`, and set them now as new start. I have to evaluate sign´s in the stream the stream is build: _(timestamp in milliseconds).(addressbyte databyte). The only what I want to display in my RichTextBox is the databyte, also I need a data management method for the timestamp. Because I have in the GUI the function that I can see the time beetween two or more databyte´s, for that I think I make a sql database. The addressbyte need I to collor the byte with an one as address in a special collor.

Question:

> How can I evaluate the stream so that i have alternately timestamp,
>   addressbyte and than databyte as single substring?

The reason why I want them so, is that, I think I can make an easy if elseif else block to realize all what I want to do.

When someone has an better suggestion for my project pls write it as comment.

With friendly wishes sniffi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve two problems at the same time. It would be better to separate them and solve them individually.

1. There is the issue of transporting the data, for this you are using streams. That is a valid solution. There is sending and receiving the data (bits) over the stream.
2. You have the problem of transforming these bits (after receiving them) into actual objects (dates, strings, etc..). For that you an use a simple parser, tokenizer, a local script that can get the correct parts from the data and convert it, or you can use a serialization framework (like DataContracts).

If you have simple data, I would opt for using a single method that can parse the data. For more complex scenarios I would look into serialization.

Also be ware that you will need to validate your inputs, since you cannot assume that there is always a trusted (non compromised) piece of software that is sending the bits to you.

Answer (score 0):

I think string is bad choice. Propably data is send as bytes. Sniff rather bytes than string. And you need protocol description to understand data. 
You need to read bytes form bus and interpret it.

Comment: The problem is when I send it as byte, I can´t set a clear start. Because my startsign come as byte too and I can never say is that a part of the timestamp or is it the startsign. I allready have test that but I didn´t find a way to set a clear start, know you a posibility?

Comment: Heve you protocol desription?

Comment: No not really my job is only receive them and show them at the window, but it must be possible to ask the time between 2 bytes and I must collorate the byte with an 9th address bit.